# Lotus Notes XPinC DateTime format issue

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I am working on a XPage application which will work on both web and client. There is an action which will adjust the date object to 20 days and store it again in the current document. I got an issue, that the code is working perfectly on web and win-xp OS XPinC. I found that there is an issue with win-7 XPinC. And compare with two different win7 machine for the same document. But working on PC but not in another. Finally concluded with that the issues is due to the current machines datetime settings. But I cannot go and check/change all the pc's datetime format. Please advice how can I handle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show your code, please. Seems your date object is stored as string. That can cause different behavior with different date/time settings on clients.

Comment: Also show us the properties for the date/time field in question on a document where you experience the issue

Comment: Code rulez and JodaTime is your friend

Comment: In the xsp.properties - do you have Timezone set to server default or browser? If it is set to browser then it will take the local client's time in XPiNC - set it to server and they should all use the same

Comment: Questions without code tend to stay unanswered for longer times than information complete questions. So if you want the issue solved - please add code and the information requested. If you have sorted it out by now, provide your own answer

Answer (score 2):

This has been doing my head in for several days.
Xpages works great in my browser, but the date/time is all screwed up when viewed in LN.

The solution is to go into "File" -> "Preferences" and then "Regional Settings".
Change "Content Language" from "English" to "English (United Kingdom)".

A pet hate of mine is that most computers default to the crazy US way of displaying the date, i.e. month/day/year when the rest of the world uses day/month/year.